# JVCL installation Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, jvcl

I have recently installed Delphi XE7 and have been adding my 3rd Party components sets. I also have Delphi 7, XE4 & XE6 on my dev machine.
When running JVCL 3.48 install I am getting the option to install or update 7, XE 4 & XE 6 but not XE 7.
What do I need to do for it to pick up this version?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 9):

The JCL and JVCL support XE7 since September 2014.

JCL: https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl
JVCL: https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl

Comment: Thanks I did pull the latest update. I am going to start from scratch again and report back

Comment: I installed using the latest compiled package (2014-10-07) and this worked 100%

http://jvcl.sourceforge.net/daily/

Comment: With the git version I get: No Delphi/BCB/BDS/RAD-Studio versions was found that has the required dependencies installed. Please install the dependencies first.

Answer (score 3):

What you should do is install from the latest version in the repo which is, as of today, held at GitHib. This has support for XE7. The link to this repo is: https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl

When you get there, follow the instructions. Step 1 is to install the JCL which is also to be found on GitHub: https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl

In fact this is generally how you should install open source projects. It takes time and effort for project maintainers to make installation programs. So you will often find that these installation programs are a little out of date. So, as a general rule, take the latest revision straight from the repo.

Comment: Your comment about the installer does not apply to JCL/JVCL because their installers are bootstrapped. It requires very little effort for them to support new versions and usually it is there at the time Delphi is released. However they don't do some official releases that often anymore it seems.

Comment: @StefanGlienke The final paragraph is general advice. And in any case it still applies here. Although it is easy to build the binary installers for JCL and JVCL, it takes more than zero effort to do it, and update the JEDI website. No matter, I doubt that you disagree with the advice to use the source repo.

Answer (score 1):

I installed using the latest compiled package (2014-10-07) and this worked 100%

http://jvcl.sourceforge.net/daily/

Thanks for the assistance all.

Comment: I wanted to follow your instructions but the supplied link is broken.

Answer (score -1):

XE7 is not supported by the installer (yet).

I hope it will be in near future.

Comment: that is a valid answer